# AWS Lambda - copy object to another S3 location

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I'd like to write a lambda python code to move files to the same S3 bucket.

***[same S3 bucket]***

/location-***as-is***/file.jpg

***[same S3 bucket]***

/location-***to-be***/file.jpg

How can I do that?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to get this to work you will need a few things. First is the lambda code itself. You should be able to use the python sdk [boto3](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.Client.copy) to make the call to copy. Here is an example how to copy your file:

```py
import json
import boto3

s3 = boto3.resource('s3')

def lambda_handler(event, context):

    my_bucket = "example-bucket"
    current_object_key = "fileA/keyA.jpg"
    new_object_key = "fileB/keyB.jpg"

    copy_source = {
        'Bucket':  my_bucket,
        'Key': current_object_key
    }
    s3.meta.client.copy(copy_source, my_bucket, new_object_key)
```

You will also need to make sure you lambda execution role has proper s3 read and write permissions and that your s3 bucket policy is configured to allow your lambda role to access it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `boto` for this purpose, as below:

```
import boto

c = boto.connect_s3()
src_buc = c.get_bucket('Source_Bucket')
sink_buc = c.get_bucket('Sink_Bucket')
```

and then you can iterate over all your keys to copy the content:

```
for k in src_buc.list():
    # copy to sink
    sink_buc.copy_key(k.key.name, src_buc.name, k.key.name)
```